# Get ASP Page to Load XML File Instead of Using Cached Version

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've got an ASP page that reads config info from an XML file like so:

```
Dim xmlConfig As New DOMDocument
xmlConfig.preserveWhiteSpace = True
xmlConfig.load(ConfigFile)
'reads the data from the file
xmlConfig = Nothing
```

The output is sent to a literal in an update panel, which updates every 10 seconds when a timer fires.

If I add or remove an element from the XML file, the change is picked up.  However, if I just change an element, the change to that element does not get picked up until IIS is reset.

I've done a good bit of searching but haven't yet found a method for forcing it to actually read the file each time so that it picks up the changes to elements, not just the element adds and deletes.  I added the `xmlConfig = Nothing` line in an attempt to get the desired behavior, but it had no impact.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I have seen something along the lines of "xmlConfig.load(ConfigFile + "?"+new Date().getTime());"  Any timetick will make it think it needs to reload.

Comment: You could also try and call the garbage collector (gc.collect) after the "=nothing", to force the disposal of the object.  Obviously I don't condone that, as you are circumventing the most efficient processing of unused resources, but for this, it may help.

Comment: I think this is only an issue in IE (or at least it used to be). You can solve it as @AnthonyHorne answered in his first post.

Comment: The XML is being loaded server-side, so the browser is not a factor here.  I just tested Chrome and it exhibits the same behavior.  I tried `xmlConfig.load(ConfigFile & "?" & TimeOfDay)` and `xmlConfig.load(ConfigFile & "?" & (New Date = TimeOfDay))` and they had no impact.

Comment: I suppose I can check the file modified time and garbage collect if it has been modified within the past 30 seconds.  Thanks @Anthony Horne.

Comment: ...or not.  GC.Collect() has no impact.

Comment: What about adding a "fake" element with the new date()?  It will be forcing it to reload even if only attributes have changed.   Not my preferred way, but desperate measures...

Comment: It's really bizarre--I can change an element, and remove or add another element and save the file.  The adds and removes are picked up, but the changed one is not.

Comment: Tried cache.remove("xmlConfig") as well...